Blurring a button in CustomTkinter
I am making a GUI and I am using customtkinter. I am wondering, how can I make a button blurred, like this:


I don't know if tkinter or  CustomTkinter can do it - but if you would use images as buttons then you could create blurred images and replace them on buttons. You could even use module Pillow to blur images.

maybe you could describe it (with minimal working code) as answer below.

I've managed to do it by using the Pillow Library. Explanation of the code:
First I create the button:
self.WarmUp = WarmUpButton(self.MenuLeft)
self.WarmUp.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.2)

then I create a label in which I place the image with the following code:
class WarmUpBlur(ctk.CTkLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(image=ctk.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open('Images/image-6.webp'),
                                          dark_image=Image.open('Images/image-6.webp'),
                                          size=(200, 40)))
        self.configure(text='')

The image is placed with the place method and then when the button is pressed i am using button.place_forget() method to remove the picture.
